# .NET MVC bundle - flattens paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have strange behavior with .NET MVC bundles.
Here is a directory structure:

```
-scripts
 - module
   - index.js
   - controllers
     - controller1.js
     - controller2.js
```

Then I include this module into bundles using

```
.IncludeDirectory("~/scipts/module", "*.js", true)
```

It renders (development mode) all the files but it ignores "controllers" folder and renders everything like:

```
- /scripts/module/index.js
- /scripts/module/controller1.js
- /scripts/module/controller2.js
```

Expected behavior would be

```
- /scripts/module/index.js
- /scripts/module/controllers/controller1.js
- /scripts/module/controllers/controller2.js
```

I was using .NET MVC bundles thousand times but can't recall of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, it only happens in the debug version:

http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/105

Not sure, but it maybe fixed in the most recent 1.1.3 version, have you updated your nuget packages to make sure?